# Page Navigation In PHP

Tags: php, html, asynchronous, hyperlink, navigation

How Make Page Navigation in php without reloading the page without jquery like facebook has.
ex. `for welcome page : http://www.facebook.com/?sk=welcome
for friends list : http://www.facebook.com/?sk=ff&ap=1
for news feed link http://www.fack.com/?sk=nf`

with clicking the link instead of reloading whole page the appropriate content be loaded.
how to do this without javascript, jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it done the same way that Facebook does, you’ll have to use JavaScript. There’s little way to do it without it.

Comment: how to make this as facebook does ?

Comment: Facebook uses JavaScript. I remember reading that they used jQuery at some point, but they’ve probably built their own library now.

Answer (score 1):

Without JS and jQuery, the only way will be an `<iframe>`.
Look at this [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) for more.